# how do i change the colour of a button based on a string input

Tags: vb.net

For my computing project I am creating a game of risk this requires me to randomly generate the initial countries of the players (I have started with 2 players for simplicity), for this I am going to have the buttons (which represent the countries) to change colour  to denote which of the players country it is.

I have tried to assign each player a string value of their colour then set the button back colour to that value. The problem with that at the moment is with the line of "b.Tag.BackColor = Players_Colours(N)" as the value that Players_Colours(N) gives is "S"c for some reason.

Any ideas why that is the case or anything would be appreciated.

```vb
Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
End Sub

Public Function Random_country_picker(ByVal players)
    Dim County_List = {"Oxfordshire", "Buckinhamshire", "Berkshire", "London", "Hampshire", "Surrey", "West_Sussex", "East_Sussex", "Kent", "Bedfordshire", "Cambridgeshire", "Hertfordshire", "Essex", "Cornwall", "Devon", "Gloucestershire", "Whiltshire", "Lancashire", "Cumbria", "Cheshire", "Manchester", "Merseyside", "Lincolnshire", "Staffordshire", "Herefordshire", "County_Durham", "North_Yorkshire", "South_Yorkshire", "Warwickshire", "Northumberland", "West_Yorkshire", "East_Yorkshire", "Shropshire", "Northamptonshire", "Derbyshire", "Nottinghamshire", "Worcestershire", "Somerset", "Dorset", "Isle_Of_White", "Norfolk", "Suffolk"}
    Dim value As String
    Dim num = 0
    Dim nump = 42 / players
    Dim N As Integer
    Dim Players_Colours As String
    Dim z As String
    Players_Colours = {"Pink", "Red"}.ToString
    N = 0
    Randomize()
    Dim rnd As New Random()
    Dim index As Integer
    While nump > num
        If N > Players_Colours.Length Then
            N = 0
        End If
        index = rnd.Next(0, County_List.Length)
        value = County_List(index)
        For Each b As Windows.Forms.Button In Me.Controls
            If b.Tag = index Then
                b.Tag.BackColor = Players_Colours(N)
            End If
        Next
        Array.Clear(County_List, index, 1)
        num += 1
        N += 1
    End While
    Return 0
End Function

Random_country_picker(2)
```

Comment: `Players_Colours` is a string, when you do `Players_Colours(N)` you are actually just getting the Nth character from that string.  You probably actually want `Players_Colours` to be declared as an array (or `List`) of `Color`, not a string. `{"Pink", "Red"}.ToString` just ends up returning "System.String[]", so getting the 0th element returns the "S" that you are seeing.

Comment: Replace your Player_Colours definition with this and it should fix that problem. `Dim Players_Colours As New List(Of System.Drawing.Color)({System.Drawing.Color.Pink, System.Drawing.Color.Red})`.  You should also **seriously** consider turning on `Option Explicit` and `Option Strict` so that you can more easily tell what type your variables actually are.